Is it correct to use "preposition + not many"? — E.g.: "a simple man with not many interests" and "I agree with not many your arguments"
I wonder in what cases the construction "preposition + not many" is correct and in what cases not.
For this purpose, I found some examples on the internet.
"The Darkness and the Light: A Philosopher Reflects upon His Fortunate Career and Those Who Made It Possible" by Charles Hartshorne, 1990:
(1) But we both realized this within few weeks and had begun to suspect it after not many days.
"Memoir of an Artist" by Amitabh SenGupta, 2014:
(2) He was completely devoted to science, Agricultural studies, and a simple man with not many interests.
"Technometrics, Volume 46" by American Society for Quality Control, 2004:
(3) The length of this review certainly indicates that much material has been presented in not many pages.
"Human rights politics and states: Burma, Cambodia, Sri Lanka" by Laksiri Fernando, 2002:
(4) Out of a population of over five million , including two million adults , the franchise was enjoyed by not many more than 200,000 male citizens.
Which of (1-4) are correct and which are not and why?
What is the rule of when it's correct to use "preposition + not many" and when not?

Update:
I was said in the comment below (1-4) are all correct.
I have a sentence which, as it seems to me, is not correct:
(5) I agree with not many your arguments.
Is (5) correct?
If not, then why are (1-4) correct whereas (5) is not?

When the meaning is partitive, you will need to use of.   I agree with not many of your arguments.   That is, with some of your arguments I agree.  P.S. You were told that all are correct, not "said".

@MichaelHarvey And if we remove "your", is the sentence correct: "I agree with not many arguments you have." ? Thanks.

No, it's wrong.

In 5, not many and your are both "determiners" (same as the, those, some, few, most,...). English doesn't always accept multiple consecutive determiners, and there are quite complex constraints on exactly when it's valid to use them.

@FumbleFingers If "I agree with not many your arguments" is incorrect because "not many" and "your" stand right near each other, then "I agree with not many arguments you have" must be correct because there isn't "your" here any more. But why is it still incorrect even without "your"? Thanks.

But "I agree with not many arguments you have" isn't "incorrect". It's just non-idiomatic (the natural phrasing is "I agree with few of your arguments").

not many is a stylistic choice (a form of litotes) that is used instead of few when the goal is to underscore the paucity rhetorically. It can come off as stilted.

Objects of prepositions are not limited to nouns; they can be noun phrases.
In after not many days, the noun phrase headed by days functions as the object of the preposition after.
Similarly, in
by not many more than 200,000 male citizens, the noun phrase not many more than 200,000 male citizens
headed by citizens functions as the object of the preposition by.
The same applies to the other examples, and they are all fine.
In (5) I agree with not many your arguments, of is missing:

I agree with not many of your arguments.

With has object not many of your arguments; of has object your arguments.  This is fine.

Also note, while adding "of" makes it idiomatic, "I agree with few of your arguments" is more so. Though Indian English might vary on this usage.
